# How to create a color ramp in ArcGIS 10 with only 10 colors

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I am trying to use the company I work for's color scheme in the maps that I am making.  I have all the RGB values for the colors, but there are only 10 different shades of each color, while the style manager's ramps need 12 shades.  Is there any way to change the number of colors in each color ramp?

Answer (score 4):

According to the arcobjects documentation it looks like you're stuck with 13 colors ...

> [IPresetColorRamp](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IPresetColorRamp_Interface/001w0000027q000000/) is designed to exactly mimic the behavior of ArcView
>   3.x's color ramps. Thus, it contains exactly 13 colors in a sequence that is defined by the order the colors are defined.

However, looking at the COM categories, it would appear that you might be able to roll your own colorramp, by implementing [IColorRamp](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IColorRamp_Interface/001w000000mw000000/) and the others that the [PresetColorRamp](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/PresetColorRampClass_Class/001w000003rq000000/) coclass implements.  You'd also need to write a propertypage class that implements the same interfaces as the [PresetColorRampPropertyPage coclass](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/PresetColorRampPropertyPageClass_Class/001z0000003n000000/).

[image]